# Symfony2 - Variable "form" does not exist when it's being passed in

Tags: forms, email, symfony

I'm working on code to send email from a contact form and the form appears correctly until I submit the form then get the following error:

`Variable "form" does not exist in AcmeEmailBundle:Default:index.html.twig at line 14`

Puzzled to what is causing this as I've dumped the 'form' variable in Twig and it's being passed in, but I'm guessing *not* during the redirect?

**Controller**

```
/**
 * @Route("/", name="contact")
 * @Template("AcmeEmailBundle:Default:index.html.twig")
 */
public function contactAction(Request $request)
{
    $form = $this->createForm(new ContactType());

    if ($request->isMethod('POST')) {
        $form->submit($request);

        if ($form->isValid()) {
            $message = \Swift_Message::newInstance()
                ->setSubject($form->get('subject')->getData())
                ->setFrom($form->get('email')->getData())
                ->setTo('example@gmail.com')
                ->setBody(
                    $this->renderView(
                        'AcmeEmailBundle:Default:index.html.twig',
                        array(
                            'ip' => $request->getClientIp(),
                            'name' => $form->get('name')->getData(),
                            'message' => $form->get('message')->getData()
                        )
                    )
                );

            $this->get('mailer')->send($message);

            $request->getSession()->getFlashBag()->add('success', 'Your email has been sent! Thanks!');

            return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('contact'));
        }
    }

    return array(
        'form' => $form->createView()
    );
}
```

**Twig**

```
{% block body %}

{% for label, flashes in app.session.flashbag.all %}
    {% for flash in flashes %}
        <div class="alert alert-{{ label }}">
            {{ flash }}
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}

<form action="{{ path('contact') }}" method="post" {{ form_enctype(form) }}>
    {{ form_widget(form) }}

    <button type="submit">Send</button>
</form>

{% endblock %}
```

**Form**

```
class ContactType extends AbstractType
{
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
    ->add('name', 'text', array(
    'attr' => array(
        'placeholder' => 'What\'s your name?',
        'pattern'     => '.{2,}' //minlength
    )
))
    ->add('email', 'email', array(
        'attr' => array(
            'placeholder' => 'So I can get back to you.'
        )
    ))
    ->add('subject', 'text', array(
        'attr' => array(
            'placeholder' => 'The subject of your message.',
            'pattern'     => '.{3,}' //minlength
        )
    ))
    ->add('message', 'textarea', array(
        'attr' => array(
            'cols' => 90,
            'rows' => 10,
            'placeholder' => 'And your message to me...'
        )
    ));
}

public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
{
    $collectionConstraint = new Collection(array(
        'name' => array(
            new NotBlank(array('message' => 'Name should not be blank.')),
            new Length(array('min' => 2))
        ),
        'email' => array(
            new NotBlank(array('message' => 'Email should not be blank.')),
            new Email(array('message' => 'Invalid email address.'))
        ),
        'subject' => array(
            new NotBlank(array('message' => 'Subject should not be blank.')),
            new Length(array('min' => 3))
        ),
        'message' => array(
            new NotBlank(array('message' => 'Message should not be blank.')),
            new Length(array('min' => 5))
        )
    ));

    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'constraints' => $collectionConstraint
    ));
}

public function getName()
{
    return 'contact';
}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message seems pretty self-explanatory. This snippet:

```
// ...
                $this->renderView(
                    'AcmeEmailBundle:Default:index.html.twig',
                    array(
                        'ip' => $request->getClientIp(),
                        'name' => $form->get('name')->getData(),
                        'message' => $form->get('message')->getData()
                    )
// ...
```

is rendering the view but not passing `form` into it. The `index.html.twig` file tries to access `form` and throws an error because you haven't sent `form` to it. I'm wondering why you would send an HTML form in an email... which leads me to think **you are using the incorrect Twig file for your SwiftMailer function**.

To fix the problem you either have to include `form` in the `renderView` function:

```
// ...
                $this->renderView(
                    'AcmeEmailBundle:Default:index.html.twig',
                    array(
                        'ip' => $request->getClientIp(),
                        'name' => $form->get('name')->getData(),
                        'message' => $form->get('message')->getData(),
                        'form' => $form->createView(),
                    )
// ...
```

or use the correct template that you're trying to send through the email (this solution seems more appropriate.)

Comment: So how would I add this in `'form' => $form->createView()?`

Comment: @chance Yes... but again I implore you to re-evaluate *why* you're using the form as the contents of your email to the user? Why aren't you using a separate template file that's actually meant to be used as the email body?

Comment: @chance Please double-check the part of the `renderView` function at `AcmeEmailBundle:Default:index.html.twig` and make sure that's the email template you want... I can guarantee you that it's wrong.

Comment: Right, I was mistyped that part as I was trying different things, am using a email.txt.twig file instead. Can you provide an example on what the content format be for the twig file?

Comment: Ok, I understand now am using this `New message from {{ name }}
Sent from {{ from }}
IP: {{ ip }}

{{ message|raw }}` Thanks for your help.

Comment: @chance A `*.txt.twig` file is just plaintext. No special formatting needed as SwiftMailer handles the encoding and headers for you. Avoid using HTML markup in this type of file. If you wish to attach an HTML message instead, use `->setBody($this->renderView('Acme:Email:message.html.twig', array('values' => $values)), 'text/html')` (replace the `renderView` with the correct values for your application accordingly.) Glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

One potential reason that you are receiving this error is that you are not actually passing the form to the view. Where you have:

```
->setBody(
$this->renderView(
'AcmeEmailBundle:Default:index.html.twig', array(
    'ip' => $request->getClientIp(),
    'name' => $form->get('name')->getData(),
    'message' => $form->get('message')->getData()
))
```

You need to do something like:

```
->setBody(
$this->renderView(
'AcmeEmailBundle:Default:index.html.twig', array(
    'ip' => $request->getClientIp(),
    'form' => $form->createView()
))
```

There are a few other troubling aspects about your code. For instance, it would be a lot better to do something like:

```
$contact = new Contact(); // Where contact is some kind of Entity
$form = $this->createForm(new ContactType(), $contact);
$form->handleRequest($request);
```

Then in your mailing process, instead of doing things like:

```
->setSubject($form->get('subject')->getData())
->setFrom($form->get('email')->getData())
```

You would do things like:

```
->setSubject($contact->getSubject())
->setFrom($contact->getEmail())
```

<strike>Another thing that I noticed is that in your controller, if the request method isn't POST you are not returning a valid Response object.</strike> Anyway, hope some of that helps.

Edit: As @sjagr points out, annotations take care of this.

Comment: [The return value of the Controller is fine since OP is using annotations](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/annotations/view.html)

Comment: And also, as @sjagr points out, the choice of template is highly suspect.

Comment: @sjagr you are absolutely correct. Didn't notice that.

Comment: Cheers, for this alternative, this was helpful.